# Android Service killed by ANR

Tags: android, service, android-anr-dialog

I have a Service in my app (created by a thread), and inside I create another thread and that is a TCP server. 
Short time after starting the thread (and fully working, receiving and handling the packages received) the service is **killed** by "timeout executing service" and ANR in my service.

This is the code of my Service and the thread that is doing all the work:

```
public class Android_Wifi_Service extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        handleStart();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void handleStart() {
        Server server=new Server(this);
        new Thread(server).run();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is my thread:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    private boolean end=false;
    private Context context;

    public Server(Context _context){
        this.context=_context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss= new ServerSocket(5552);

            while(!end){
                //wait for connection
                System.out.println("Server Waiting connection");
                Socket s=ss.accept();
                SenderMessage msg=null;
                // connected 
                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                ObjectInputStream obj=new ObjectInputStream(is);
                try {
                    msg= ( SenderMessage ) obj.readObject();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Message Receive Error", e.toString());
                }
                obj.close();
                is.close();
                s.close();
                if(msg!=null){
                    // do somethings
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Messages Server", e.toString());
        }

    }   
}
```

And this is the logcat:

```
> 05-26 13:48:39.019: W/ActivityManager(1364): Timeout executing
> service: ServiceRecord{407b1838
> wifi/.auxiliar.Android_Wifi_Service} 05-26
> 13:48:39.179: I/Process(1364): Sending signal. PID: 4129 SIG: 3 05-26
> 13:48:39.179: I/dalvikvm(4129): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3 05-26
> 13:48:39.219: I/dalvikvm(4129): Wrote stack traces to
> '/data/anr/traces.txt' 05-26 13:48:39.229: I/Process(1364): Sending
> signal. PID: 1364 SIG: 3 05-26 13:48:39.229: I/dalvikvm(1364):
> threadid=4: reacting to signal 3 05-26 13:48:39.329: I/dalvikvm(1364):
> Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 05-26 13:48:39.339:
> I/Process(1364): Sending signal. PID: 1452 SIG: 3 05-26 13:48:39.339:
> I/dalvikvm(1452): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3 05-26 13:48:39.379:
> I/dalvikvm(1452): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 05-26
> 13:48:39.389: I/Process(1364): Sending signal. PID: 1433 SIG: 3 05-26
> 13:48:39.389: I/dalvikvm(1433): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3 05-26
> 13:48:39.419: I/dalvikvm(1433): Wrote stack traces to
> '/data/anr/traces.txt' 05-26 13:48:39.919: D/dalvikvm(1364):
> GC_CONCURRENT freed 1086K, 42% free 5485K/9351K, external 1223K/1735K,
> paused 7ms+12ms 05-26 13:48:40.089: D/dalvikvm(1364): GC_EXPLICIT
> freed 116K, 41% free 5529K/9351K, external 1223K/1735K, paused 108ms
> 05-26 13:48:40.829: E/ActivityManager(1364): ANR in
> wifi:Service 05-26 13:48:40.829:
> E/ActivityManager(1364): Reason: Executing service
> wifi/.auxiliar.Android_Wifi_Service
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not start a `Thread` by calling `run()`. You start a `Thread` by calling `start()`. Right now, you are simply calling your own `Thread`'s `run()` method on the main application thread.